# issue uploading files with name containing apostrophe

Tags: php, file

when trying to upload  a file with name containing an apostrophe
for example '123'456.jpg'

the server return this error :

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete >your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@****.com to inform them of the time >this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument >to handle the request.

the PHP file i used with the name of 'test.php' (no PHP code in it)  :

```
<?php
//no php code (error come before it reach the PHP code) 
?>
<form class='panel file hide'  method='post' action='/test.php' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<input  type='file' name ='file' /> 
<input  type='submit' /> 

</form>
```

how can i solve this issue ?

PS: this problem only appear on web host server,but
dose not appear on my  localhost server (xampp).

Comment: I only see the html part... where is the php part handling the form (and copying the file). And what does your error log say?

Comment: Do an escape on the variable containing the name.

Comment: @giorgio
there is no php code , it's empty. the error come with no PHP code (before it reach the PHP code)

Comment: Please see my answer after edit

Answer (score 0):

You hosting / server had "mod_security" activated, 
which will block the file by default.

Try to contact them for disable this.

Comment: I plussed it (someone voted it down), because I think this is a very likely problem. BUT: poster, please retrieve the error from the apache error log, that should give you the answer

Comment: it seams not a very good idea to me to disable something like mod_security ?!  even if i didn't try to  see if it works

Comment: Then don't upload files with apostrophe

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue. I used a function to validate the inputs and it corrected it for me.

I used:

```
function validateInput($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;   
}
```

then use:

```
$file_name = validateInput($_FILES['file']);
```

I hope this works for you :)

Also just noticed:

here:

```
<input  type='file' name ='file' />
```

you have a space between the **=** and **name**

Comment: it dose not even reach the PHP code 
the error appear before the PHP code begin

Comment: Right, Well it would have been good to know all the facts before posting an answer to you, Makes my answer look stupid now :/ - Have you got PHP turned on, on your server?  Try changing your html form to have " instead of ' because the ' in the name will cause it to end that statement.

Comment: Also, did you downvote me just because you didn't provide enough information initially and thus got a wrong reply? bad form, especially when i'm trying to help you.

Comment: i did what you said about the HTML ,and nothing happened .
i am not the one who voted you down ,i can't vote down i am a new user

Comment: @user3398690 What do you mean nothing happened with the HTML? You took out all PHP and checked the page? and then nothing loaded? is that correct?